# Upload CSV to multiple tables of DB

Tags: php, mysql, csv, upload

I'm a beginner to this topic. I want to upload a balance sheet or CSV file into multiple tables of database, Pls help me out with code or instructions, Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

go to phpmyadmin then select the database and table and select import.
then upload the csv.
do this to other table too[this image will show how to upload your csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myJpb.jpg)

Comment: I have to upload one CSV file into multiple tables in one go